# C# Datagridview - Row back colour not working per row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have three checkboxes on my access database and depending on which ones are checked, I want each row within the Datagridview to be a specific colour.

> - **True, False, False** - *Row should be Blue*
> - **False, False, False** - *Row should be Yellow*
> - **True, True, False** - *Row should be Red*
> - **True, False, True** - *Row should be Green*

My code below seems to work properly when I filter my database but not when I view all entries (it just makes all rows one colour [yellow]).

Here is the code I've written so far:

```
private void sJDataGridView_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
                {
                    Color viewModeColour = Color.White; // Default Colour
                    Color viewModeColourRGB = Color.FromArgb(viewModeColour.R, viewModeColour.G, viewModeColour.B);
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in sJDataGridView.Rows)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[14].Value) == true)
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[15].Value) == true)
                            {
                                viewModeColour = Color.FromArgb(0xFF8787); // Red
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[16].Value) == false)
                                {
                                    viewModeColour = Color.FromArgb(0xE3F7FF); // Blue
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    viewModeColour = Color.FromArgb(0xE5FFCC); // Green
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[15].Value) == false)
                            {
                                if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[16].Value) == false)
                                {
                                    viewModeColour = Color.FromArgb(0xFFFDCC); // Yellow
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        viewModeColourRGB = Color.FromArgb(viewModeColour.R, viewModeColour.G, viewModeColour.B);
                    }
         
                    for (int i = 0; i < sJDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        sJDataGridView.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = viewModeColourRGB;
                    }    
                     
                }
            }
```

Comment: try moving the assignment of the colour inside the first loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check each of  your condition in different `if` statement block.

And apply `DefaultCellStyle` inside your `foreach` block.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in sJDataGridView.Rows)
{
    bool a = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[14].Value);
    bool b = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[15].Value);
    bool c = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[16].Value);

    if (a == true && b == false && c == false)
        viewModeColour = Color.FromArgb(0xE3F7FF); // Blue

    if (a == false && b == false && c == false)
        viewModeColour = Color.FromArgb(0xFFFDCC); // Yellow

    if (a == true && b == true && c == false)
        viewModeColour = Color.FromArgb(0xFF8787); // Red

    if (a == true && b == false && c == true)
        viewModeColour = Color.FromArgb(0xE5FFCC); // Green

    viewModeColourRGB = Color.FromArgb(viewModeColour.R, viewModeColour.G, viewModeColour.B);
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = viewModeColourRGB;
}
```

Comment: @J.James, glad to hear,  vote up if possible by clicking up arrow to answer :)